# How can I build correctly the body post in retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to post some data with retrofit 2 but I'm gettins some problems... and don't find any example like this...

This is the body that I have to send:

```
{
    "birthday": "12-01-1987",
    "name": bob,
    "activity": {
        "activity_preferences": {
            "user_subjects": [4,7,8],
            "user_allergies": [1,6,10],
        }   
    }
}
```

This is my data class:

```
data class GenericFormDataEntity(
    var birthday: String,
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("activity")
    var food: ActivityEntity?
)

data class ActivityEntity(@SerializedName("activity_preferences")val activityPreferences: ActivityPreferencesEntity)

data class ActivityPreferencesEntity(@SerializedName("user_Subjects")var userSubjects:List<Int>?,@SerializedName("user_allergies")var userAllergies: List<Int>?)
```

This is the method that I'm trying to build the json:

```
fun getUserFormEntity(): String{
        val paramObject = JSONObject()
        paramObject.put("birthday", birthday)
        paramObject.put("name", name)
        paramObject.put("activity", getActivityEntity())

        return paramObject.toString()
    }

private fun getActivityEntity(): ActivityEntity{
       return ActivityEntity(ActivityPreferencesEntity(selectedSubjectList, selecteAllergiesList))
    }
```

And this is the json that is returning me:

```
{\"birthday\":\"23-12-2019\",\"name\":Bob,"activity\":\"ActivityEntity(activity_preferences=ActivityPreferencesEntity(user_Subjects=[4,7,8], user_allergies=[1,6,10])"}"
```

My question is, how can I get the correct json that I have to send as a body:

```
  @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @POST("xxxxxxxx")
    suspend fun saveUserData(@Body userFormData: String)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to stringify `getActivityEntity` using `Gson`.

```
Gson.toJson(getActivityEntity())
```

Also, from your API I infer that you are using retrofit why not pass along the entire instance of `GenericFormDataEntity` as the body for your API.

For enabling this you need to follow by adding **GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)** to your retrofit.

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .callFactory(okHttpClient)
        .build()
```